# Retry rest calls to external APIs for selected set of Http error status codes

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-retry

in order to add retry utility to external API calls, I am thinking of using Spring `@Retryable` annotation as follows:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

  @Retryable(maxAttempts=3, value = Exception.class, 
             backoff = @Backoff(delay = 100, multiplier = 2))
  public List<String> doCallExternalResource() {
     // ...
  }

}
```

I would like to do retries for the following errors:

```
1. 500 Internal Server Error
2. 502 Bad Gateway
3. 503 Service Unavailable
4. 504 Gateway Timeout
```

But I am not able to understand, how can I do this with the `@Retryable` annotation approach.

Could anyone please help here? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Retryable annotation is used to call a service method and, if it fails with a specific exception that you specify on `@Retryable`, it try again according to maxAttempts (by default is 3, in your case too).
You can use `@Recover` annotation to specify what the method should do if method with Retryable annotation fails. More in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/annotation/Retryable.html).

For example:

```
@Service
class Coordinate {
    @Retryable(GatewayTimeout.class)
    public void service() {
        // ...main method
    }
    @Recover
    public void recover(GatewayTimeout e) {
       // do something if SQLException occurs 3 times.
    }
}
```

In your case, you may use GatewayTimeout.class instead of HttpServerErrorException.GATEWAY_TIMEOUT

Comment: thanks for the answer. I was actually looking for if there is any way so that we can do a retry for a set of error codes: say, if I want to retry for only HttpServerErrorException.BAD_GATEWAY and HttpServerErrorException.GATEWAY_TIMEOUT,  how would I be able to do this with @Retry?

Comment: You may try to use the name of the specific exception instead of HttpServerErrorException, like:
``
@Service
class Coordinate {
    @Retryable(GatewayTimeout.class)
    public void service() {
        // ...main method
    }
    @Recover
    public void recover(BadGateway e) {
       // do something if SQLException occurs 3 times.
    }
}
``

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a custom http client to achieve this and call using that custom http cleint. Here is an example

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy(new ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy() {
        @Override
        public boolean retryRequest(
                final HttpResponse response, final int executionCount, final HttpContext context) {
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            return statusCode == 500 || statusCode == 502 || statusCode == 503 || statusCode == 504; 
        }

        @Override
        public long getRetryInterval() {
            return 0;
        }
    })
    .build();
```

You should also limit the number of retry otherwise retry will happen infinite times until succeed. You can limit the number of retry on *executionCount* parameters